# Pulling a value from an array & having it populate on a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, getelementsbyname

working on getting the value from an array that has random numbers added to it to populate in a list.  The math.random is working & the numbers are populating in the array.  The function that adds them to the list is not.  Tried using .attr to add a name to the array, didn't work, may have just been going about it the wrong way.  I feel like the issue is somewhere in this:
var newNum = document.getElementsByName(numList[0]).value,
but after a lot of reworking this line I can't figure out what I'm missing/wording wrong.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
<script>
    var numList = [];

    function myFunction() {
        var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        document.getElementById('mathVal').value = rnd;
        numList.push(rnd);

        console.log(numList);

        buildList();
    }


    console.log(numList); //Working


    function buildList() {
        var newNum = document.getElementsByName(numList[0]),

            listNode = document.getElementById("newList"),
            liNode = document.createElement("LI"),
            txtNode = document.createTextNode(newNum);

        liNode.appendChild(txtNode);
        listNode.appendChild(liNode);

        console.log(newNum); //Not working, Getting undefined
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByName()` returns an array. There is no `.value` of the array.

Comment: Try wrap the name tag with "" quotations    var newNum = document.getElementsByName("numList")[0].value;